# Comptablity testing in IE and Mozilla

Tags: html, testing, cross-browser

I want to do comptiblity testing for asp applications in IE 7 and Mozilla. Is there any tool available for testing. Which should be free.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to do cross browser testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565505/whats-the-best-way-to-do-cross-browser-testing)

Answer (score 0):

w3c validation services offer a plethora of tools for testing all types of applications. sadly, if you're building in ASP, they're going to disagree with most everything you are doing; however, if you comply with the validators, the majority of the differences between gecko and trident are marginalized.

i build with standards first, knowing that all of the modern browsers will (more likely than not) play nicely. once it's functioning in the real world i'll go back and visit Trident and the lesser than market value browsers and address the problem(s) on a per browser basis (99% of the time targeting Trident(s) via conditional comments.

you're probably thinking that doesn't answer your question, but it most certainly does. developing with web standards is the most effective and productive way to approach cross-browser/cross-media/cross-platform sites/applications.

if you are asking for unit tests, jade https://github.com/weepy/jade-browser, selenium http://seleniumhq.org/ and cucumber http://cukes.info/ offer automated testing, however idk of any ASP instances of them.